# Why is my custom template not showing anything?

Tags: posts

**UPDATE 1:** I tried creating a new page and the header and footer is showing, but not the posts.
**UPDATE 2:** If I update the Reading settings to Post page and select the page I created with the custom template, nothing is showing.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog Template */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<h1>Blog posts</h1>

<div class="container">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template for displaying all your posts should not be a custom page template. You should set the page you want to use as your Posts page in *Settings > Reading*. Then, as per the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), your theme will automatically use `home.php` for this page, or `index.php` if that does not exist.

So you should save your template as `home.php`, without the `/* Template Name: Blog Template */` comment, and set the page you want to use for displaying posts in *Settings > Reading*.

Comment: Thanks that works! I forgot that WordPress uses the homepage to display all posts.